# Tensorflow estimator with shared network

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am building a tensorflow model with new [estimator](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/Estimator) high-level api. My model looks like below screenshot

[image: this].

In fact, the model is more complex than that due to the model is used to simulate game operation. Classification is responsible for decide whether it is good time for action. Then the regression will give the details about the action. It contains a combination of CNN and RNN.

However, due to the complexity and memory consumption, it is impossible to train and run classification and regression as two network simultaneously. Also, when I create my estimator like:

```
# Create the Estimator
mnist_classifier = tf.estimator.Estimator(
    model_fn=cnn_model_fn, model_dir="/tmp/mnist_convnet_model")
```

I can only provide one model function for the estimator. Is it possible to train and run two estimator together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your loss function to be a linear combination of regression and classification losses. It will be one estimator with one loss, but multiple inferences.